# Do all kafka brokers at all points of time contain the same amount of data for a specific topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Do all kafka brokers at all points of time contain the same amount of data for a specific topic. I am trying to understand if subscribing to a single broker in a cluster of lets say 3 brokers work? Will it be enough to read all logs inside the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Producers write only to the leader broker at a given time, then there is some delay, depending on your `acks` config if there is a replica available for that partition or not (assuming you have `replication.factor > 1` and `min.in.sync.replicas > 1` on the topic)

Similarly, in the event of an unclean leader election, then data in the topic can be truncated due to network segregation, for example.

> subscribing to a single broker in a cluster of lets say 3 brokers work? Will it be enough to read all logs inside the topic.

Yes. Consumers also only read from leader partitions, or in-sync followers.